# Trouble migrating services from Spring Framework to Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jboss

I migrate a project in Spring Framework to Spring Boot, the project  developed some time ago by an other person.

The project are services, they use AWS, Spring Security, JPA, and more things, and has to be deployed in JBoss 7.1. So they are change from services to microservices (I really don't know a lot about the project nor Spring Framework nor Spring Boot).

I was following this tutorial:

[Migrting from Spring to](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-migration)

I have changed a lot of times the versions of some libraries, add them, excluded them (to avoid collitions between spring and spring boot) etc.

but im couldnt have deploy it yet (right now im trying to deploy on tomcat, the default, because i've tried with JBoss and it was a mess i followed this tutorial : [How to deploy spring boot in JBoss/wildfire](https://thepracticaldeveloper.com/2017/09/02/how-to-deploy-a-spring-boot-war-in-wildfly-jboss/))

the last exception is a BeanCreationException

here it is:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. Application startup failed


org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter': Cannot create inner bean 'org.springframework.data.web.PageableArgumentResolver#0' of type [org.springframework.data.web.PageableArgumentResolver] while setting bean property 'customArgumentResolvers' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.data.web.PageableArgumentResolver#0' defined in class path resource [spring-mvc.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.web.PageableArgumentResolver]: Specified class is an interface
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:313) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:122) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:382) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1533) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1280) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.12.RELEASE.jar:1.5.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.12.RELEASE.jar:1.5.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.12.RELEASE.jar:1.5.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.12.RELEASE.jar:1.5.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.12.RELEASE.jar:1.5.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.12.RELEASE.jar:1.5.12.RELEASE]
at com.miapp.svr.MiApp.main(MiApp.java:15) [classes/:na]
```

and my pom.xml only properties, and dependecy

```
    <properties>
    <!-- == Google == -->
    <com.google.guava.version>14.0.1</com.google.guava.version>
    <!-- == Apache Commons == -->
    <commons-beanutils.version>1.8.3</commons-beanutils.version>
    <commons-collections.version>3.2.1</commons-collections.version>
    <commons-dbcp.version>1.2.2</commons-dbcp.version>
    <commons-pool.version>1.6</commons-pool.version>
    <commons-io.version>2.4</commons-io.version>
    <commons-lang.version>3.1</commons-lang.version>
    <!-- == Dozer== -->
    <dozer.version>5.4.0</dozer.version>
    <!-- == Joda-Time == -->
    <joda-time.version>2.2</joda-time.version>
    <joda-time.joda-time-jsptags.version>1.1.1</joda-time.joda-time-jsptags.version>
    <jadira-usertype-core.version>3.0.0.GA</jadira-usertype-core.version>
    <!-- == AspectJ == -->
    <org.aspectj-version>1.7.3</org.aspectj-version>
    <!-- == Jackson == -->
    <org.codehaus.jackson.version>1.9.7</org.codehaus.jackson.version>
    <!-- == JPA == -->
    <org.hibernate.javax.persistence.version>1.0.1.Final</org.hibernate.javax.persistence.version>
    <org.hibernate.version>4.2.4.Final</org.hibernate.version>
    <!-- == BeanValidation == -->
    <javax.validation.version>1.0.0.Final</javax.validation.version>
    <org.hibernate.hibernate-validator.version>4.3.1.Final</org.hibernate.hibernate-validator.version>
    <!-- == Logging == -->
    <org.slf4j-version>1.7.5</org.slf4j-version>
    <ch.qos.logback.version>1.1.3</ch.qos.logback.version>
    <org.lazyluke.version>0.2.7</org.lazyluke.version>
    <!-- == Spring Framework == -->
    <org.springframework-version>4.3.16.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.springframework.data.spring-data-jpa.version>1.3.4.RELEASE</org.springframework.data.spring-data-jpa.version>
    <org.springframework.data.version>1.5.2.RELEASE</org.springframework.data.version>
    <org.springframework.security.version>3.1.4.RELEASE</org.springframework.security.version>
    <!-- == Tiles == -->
    <org.apache.tiles.version>2.2.2</org.apache.tiles.version>
    <!-- == Amateras == -->
    <jp.sf.amateras.functions.version>1.1.2</jp.sf.amateras.functions.version>
    <!-- == JavaEE/SE APIs == -->
    <javax.inject.version>1</javax.inject.version>
    <javax.servlet.jstl.version>1.2</javax.servlet.jstl.version>
    <javax.transaction.version>1.1</javax.transaction.version>
    <tomcat.api.version>7.0.40</tomcat.api.version>
    <!-- == database == -->
    <com.h2database.version>1.3.156</com.h2database.version>
    <!-- == JUnit == -->
    <junit.version>4.7</junit.version>
    <org.mockito.version>1.9.0</org.mockito.version>
    <selenium.version>2.32.0</selenium.version>
    <!-- == Maven Plugins == -->
    <maven-eclipse-plugin.version>2.6</maven-eclipse-plugin.version>
    <maven-jxr-plugin.version>2.3</maven-jxr-plugin.version>
    <net.sourceforge.nekohtml.version>1.9.15</net.sourceforge.nekohtml.version>
    <org.apache.maven.archetype.version>2.2</org.apache.maven.archetype.version>
    <org.apache.maven.plugins.maven-checkstyle-plugin.version>2.9.1</org.apache.maven.plugins.maven-checkstyle-plugin.version>
    <org.apache.maven.plugins.maven-compiler-plugin.version>2.5.1</org.apache.maven.plugins.maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    <org.apache.maven.plugins.maven-dependency-plugin.version>2.5</org.apache.maven.plugins.maven-dependency-plugin.version>
    <org.apache.maven.plugins.maven-javadoc-plugin.version>2.8.1</org.apache.maven.plugins.maven-javadoc-plugin.version>
    <org.apache.maven.plugins.maven-project-info-reports-plugin.version>2.5.1</org.apache.maven.plugins.maven-project-info-reports-plugin.version>
    <org.apache.maven.plugins.maven-resources-plugin.version>2.6</org.apache.maven.plugins.maven-resources-plugin.version>
    <org.apache.maven.plugins.maven-site-plugin.version>3.1</org.apache.maven.plugins.maven-site-plugin.version>
    <org.apache.maven.plugins.maven-source-plugin.version>2.2</org.apache.maven.plugins.maven-source-plugin.version>
    <org.apache.maven.plugins.maven-war-plugin.version>2.2</org.apache.maven.plugins.maven-war-plugin.version>
    <org.apache.maven.plugins.version>2.5</org.apache.maven.plugins.version>
    <org.apache.maven.plugins.version>2.9</org.apache.maven.plugins.version>
    <org.apache.maven.wagon.version>1.0-beta-7</org.apache.maven.wagon.version>
    <org.apache.tomcat.maven.version>2.1</org.apache.tomcat.maven.version>
    <org.codehaus.mojo.emma-maven-plugin.version>1.0-alpha-3</org.codehaus.mojo.emma-maven-plugin.version>
    <org.codehaus.mojo.version>2.5</org.codehaus.mojo.version>
    <!-- == Other Properties== -->
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <archetype.test.skip>true</archetype.test.skip>
    <com.google.code.findbugs.version>1.3.9</com.google.code.findbugs.version>
    <com.google.code.maven-license-plugin.version>1.4.0</com.google.code.maven-license-plugin.version>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    <java-version>1.7</java-version>
</properties>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- == Begin Google == -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>${com.google.guava.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
<groupId>com.google.maps</groupId>
<artifactId>google-maps-services</artifactId>
<version>0.1.7</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.2</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>     
        <version>4.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- == End Google == -->
    <!-- == Begin Apache Commons == -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-beanutils.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-collections.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-io.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-dbcp.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-pool.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-lang.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- == End Apache Commons == -->
    <!-- == Begin Dozer== -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.dozer</groupId>
        <artifactId>dozer</artifactId>
        <version>${dozer.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- == End Dozer== -->
    <!-- == Begin Joda-Time == -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>${joda-time.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time-jsptags</artifactId>
        <version>${joda-time.joda-time-jsptags.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
        <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
        <version>${jadira-usertype-core.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.joda</groupId>
                <artifactId>joda-money</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- == End Joda-Time == -->
    <!-- == Begin AspectJ == -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- == End AspectJ == -->
    <!-- == Begin Jackson == -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>${org.codehaus.jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>${org.codehaus.jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- == End Jackson == -->
    <!-- == Begin JPA == -->
    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${org.hibernate.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
                <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
                <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- JPA API 2.0 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.hibernate.javax.persistence.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- == End JPA == -->
    <!-- == Begin BeanValidation == -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>${org.hibernate.hibernate-validator.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- == End BeanValidation == -->
    <!-- == Begin Logging == -->
    <!-- SLF4J -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Logback -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>${ch.qos.logback.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>${ch.qos.logback.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Log4JDBC -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lazyluke</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4jdbc-remix</artifactId>
        <version>${org.lazyluke.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- == End Logging == -->
    <!-- == Begin Spring == -->
    <!-- Spring Framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring MVC -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Data -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- == Para el web service jax ws debi importar la de abajo == -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- == Begin Tiles == -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.apache.tiles.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>${org.apache.tiles.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- == End Tiles == -->
    <!-- == Begin Other JavaEE/SE APIs == -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.servlet.jstl.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.transaction.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.inject.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
       <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
       <version>1.4.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- == End Other JavaEE/SE APIs == -->
    <!-- == Begin Unit Test == -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>${org.mockito.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- == End Unit Test == -->
    <!-- == Begin Amateras == -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jp.sf.amateras.functions</groupId>
        <artifactId>functions</artifactId>
        <version>${jp.sf.amateras.functions.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jsonic</artifactId>
                <groupId>net.arnx</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- == End Amateras == -->
    <!-- == Begin H2DataBase == -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>${com.h2database.version}</version>
        <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
    </dependency>
    <!-- == End H2DataBase == -->
    <!-- == Begin Tomcat == -->
    <!-- Servlet API 3.0 & JSP API 2.2 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.api.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.api.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency> -->
    <!-- == End Tomcat == -->
    <!-- == Conversion BASE64 == -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- == VALIDADOR DE TARJETAS == -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- == AMAZON S3 == -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.62</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>net.java.dev.jets3t</groupId>
        <artifactId>jets3t</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- == OPENPAY == -->
    <dependency>
    <groupId>mx.openpay</groupId>
    <artifactId>openpay-api-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.5</version>
  </dependency>
<!-- == Android Async Http   == -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.loopj.android</groupId>
    <artifactId>android-async-http</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20151123</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.1</version> <!-- makesure correct version here -->
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
    <version>4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

thanks, i didnt notice about the links, so i fix it, an here is myApp code:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MiApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MiApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

or maybe you have another suggestion about the approach in the tutorials
thank you

Comment: Let's fix your typos, missing 2 links, add more information.

Comment: need more info can u paste MiApp contents ?